# Mysql command to sort address by street name then number

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched and couldn't find a solution that exactly fit my needs.  I have a mysql command that needs to be modified, but I am stuck like chuck.  The following code sorts by street name, but I also need it to sort by the # afterward.  Here is what code I have:

```
SELECT * from property_details 
ORDER BY SUBSTR(LTRIM(address), LOCATE(' ',LTRIM(address))) ASC
```

Doing so does this:

```
320 Booken Pine
803 E. Cordy Ct.
2046 Last Fine Court
2000 Last Fine Court
2019 Last Fine Court
27-A Persons Alley
27-B Persons Alley
```

and I need it to do this:

```
320 Booken Pine
803 E. Cordy Ct.
2000 Last Fine Court
2019 Last Fine Court
2046 Last Fine Court
27-A Persons Alley
27-B Persons Alley
```

Any help GREATLY appreciated.  Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second `ORDER BY` criteria to sort rows with the same street name by the number.

```
SELECT * from property_details 
ORDER BY SUBSTR(LTRIM(address), LOCATE(' ',LTRIM(address))) ASC, 
         LEFT(address, LOCATE(' ',LTRIM(address)) ASC
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar for your help!  However, after swapping out mysql commands, in my php, it no longer shows the list at all.  Is it because there is a bracket or comma missing somewhere?

Comment: Ah it was a bracket - I added and it runs thanks!  One more thing:

Comment: ...One thing 
I noticed that 14 Prim Way precedes 5 Prim Way.  How can I get it to be switched, since 5 is smaller than 14?  EDIT:  I got it!  For anyone who wants to see how it was done, here it is: 

SELECT * from property_details ORDER BY SUBSTR(LTRIM(address), LOCATE(' ',LTRIM(address))) ASC, convert(SUBSTRING_INDEX(address, ' ', 1), UNSIGNED INTEGER)

Thanks again so much Barmar - I couldn't have done it without you!

Comment: You need to convert it to a number. But then things like `27-A` and `27-B` won't work, because `A` and `B` aren't numbers.